# Angular Reactive forms model value not updating

Tags: angular

It's hard to give an easy example but sometimes I've seen when creating a reactive form, when I console log out the entire model, that the "controls" object values for the individual controls values don't match the values within the "value" object. Has anyone else experienced this? I'll try to show an example which can best convey this.

It's almost like I'm missing maybe an angular function which force updates everything?

Comment: Can you include some piece of your code to the question?

Comment: Are you using ngmodel with reactive forms? It might be better to explicitly call `.value` to get the data

Comment: Ah I found it out, I was going down too far when pushing a new group to a form array. I've just posted the answer. Thanks for your replies my friends :)

Answer (score 0):

Ah I found the answer in the end. This issue only happened with form arrays.
Specifically the issue was as to how I was pushing a new group to an array.
Before I had this:

```
this.myForm.controls['emailContentPage']['controls'][this.viewingEmailContentPageIndex]['controls']['blocks']['controls'].push(this.fb.group({
myField: "hello"
}));
});
```

And I should have stopped at "blocks" and not going into controls. This was the correction:

```
this.myForm.controls['emailContentPage']['controls'][this.viewingEmailContentPageIndex]['controls']['blocks'].push(this.fb.group({
myField: "hello"
}));
});
```